# Undefined function 'laguerreL' for input arguments of type 'sym'

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, undefined

I am trying to evaluate an integral containing a sum and Laguerre polynomials.

These are my commands:

```
m=4;
t=4;
n=5;
P=10;
syms x;
syms k;
mean=int(log(1+P*x/t)*symsum( (laguerreL(n-m,k,x))^2,k,[0,m-1]),x,0,inf);
```

The error message:
Undefined function 'laguerreL' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using a MuPAD notebook?

Comment: I don't know what is a MuPAD notebook, but I am using a script (directly in matlab) to code.

Comment: The very first line in [the documentation for `laguerreL`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/laguerrel.html) states: `Use only in the MuPAD Notebook Interface. This functionality does not run in MATLAB.` Please see the [getting started documentation for MuPad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html).

Comment: However, if you are able to update Matlab to the R2014b release or later, [`laguerreL`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laguerrel.html) has been overloaded to work with the Symbolic Toolbox in Matlab proper.

Comment: @mat: in the future it would probably be best to ask such a question in the comments to my answer. First, you've not indicated what `version` of Matlab you're using. Second, since it's an old one, make sure to look at the built-in documentation, not what comes up in Google (however three input arguments are supported all the way back to R2009a). Third, do `clear all` and `reset(symengine)`. Then, does `syms x k;` `feval(symengine,'laguerreL',1,k,x)` still produce the error? If so, what does `symengine` by itself return?

Comment: It works, thank you!. However, I got 'int(log((5*x)/2 + 1)*(x*exp(-x)*(x - 1)^2 + 2*x*exp(-x)*(x - 2)^2 + 12*x*exp(-x)*(x - 3)^2 + 144*x*exp(-x)*(x - 4)^2), x, 0, Inf)' as a final answer. It seems that Matlab is unable to compute this integral. Any idea?

Comment: @horchler Notice that in my example I gave a simplified expression ( it is not the full expression..). For next time I will consider your remarks.

Comment: @mat: That's a separate question and should be asked as such (with the actual full expression) if you are unable to find an answer after researching it. Is `xexp` a typo maybe? I recommend reading the documentation for `int`, trying the options, and searching on this site where many have already asked about what to do when `int` doesn't return a result. Also, many (even much simpler) integrals just don't have closed form solutions. Finally, please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) about how to properly format inline code: use backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: @horchler if you can take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624985/error-using-mupadmex-error-in-sym-symsum-evaluate-a-definite-integral), I would be very grateful..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the version of your MATLAB, for me this work with `2014b`

```
m=4;
t=4;
n=5;
P=10;
syms x;
syms k;
mean=int(log(1+P*x/t)*symsum( (laguerreL(n-m,k,x))^2,k,[0,m-1]),x,0,inf);
>> mean

mean =

Inf
```