# Error using mupadmex, Error in sym/symsum (Evaluate a definite integral)

Tags: matlab, mupad

I am trying to evaluate a definite integral using the following code :

```
m=4;
t=4;
n=5;
P=10;
reset(symengine)
syms x;
syms k;

mean=int(log(1+P*x/t)*symsum( factorial(k)*x^(n-m)*exp(-x)/factorial(k+n-m)*feval(symengine,'laguerreL',n-m,k,x)*feval(symengine,'laguerreL',n-m,k,x),k,[0,m-1]) ,x,0,inf)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
  Error using mupadmex
  Error in MuPAD command: The number of arguments is incorrect. [has]
  Evaluating: sum

  Error in sym/symsum (line 114)
  rSym = mupadmex('symobj::map',fsym.s,'symobj::symsum',x.s,a.s,b.s);

  Error in Untitled2 (line 32)
  mean=int(log(1+P*x/t)*symsum( factorial(k)*x^(n-m)*exp(-x)/factorial(k+n-m)*feval(symengine,'laguerreL',n-m,k,x)*feval(symengine,'laguerreL',n-m,k,x),k,[0,m-1]) ,x,0,inf)
```

However, when I evaluate the integral without some functions:

```
mean=int(log(1+P*x/t)*symsum( feval(symengine,'laguerreL',n-m,k,x)*feval(symengine,'laguerreL',n-m,k,x),k,[0,m-1]) ,x,0,inf)
```

I get an answer which is `Inf`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. it consists in using gamma(k+n-m+1) to compute (k+n-m)!, since there is a bug when performing the factorial of a symbolic variables.